# File loads ftp but not http

Tags: ftp, html

I uploaded a file via ftp and the ftp link to that file works but when I try to access the file http, I get page not found

Comment: more info will be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell. Description is too brief. You can have mistake in your URL. Other possibility is server configuration. Sometimes changes needs time to be seen (because of proxy ...).

Answer (score 0):

Those are different protocols. FTP = file transfer protocol, HTTP = Hypertext Transfer Protocol. Your HTTP server needs to be aware of the file (and location) to serve it over that protocol

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the FTP site has been mapped to a folder in your web site based on your user name. Try /username/file to see if you can get to it from HTTP.

Like everyone else is saying though, more information will help diagnose the problem.

Comment: I have no problem accessing other files uploaded via http but this m4a file can only be accessed ftp, when trying to access http I get page not found

Comment: depending on your web server, it may not send files to the client that it doesn't know the associated mime type of. IIS 7 (for example) by default won't send M4A files unless you go in and tell it that M4A files have a mime type of audio/mp4
Here's some instructions on adding a mime type in IIS
[Add a MIME Type in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned in a comment that 'all other files work (via http) except for this m4a file, which wont.

Sounds like its one of two things (and most probably the latter)

1) its a permissions problem (and good luck with that)

2) your webserver (or your webserver's admin) won't let you host .m4a files.

There should be an easy way to check. Upload a second .m4a file and see if you can download that via HTTP.

If this fails then rename one of the files .txt and try and download it. (if this works then you are having file names blocked by extension).

You could also try and upload a TEXT file and rename it `text.m4a` see if you can download this. If you can, then the server is actually checking the filetype rather than the last three letters of the name.

---

You want to know how to host these music files? Stick them in a zip file ;)

Answer (score 0):

Different protocols to access the same server don't necessarily share the same path:

Files uploaded to FTP may be located for example at c:\ftp_root while files available for http access may be located at C:\inetpub\wwwroot.